# Getting DeadLock while updating the table

Tags: spring, sql-server-2005, mybatis

We are using spring + mybatis +sqlserver.

Scenario is something like we have a table, suppose transaction_table. We received some data while using jdbc inbound channel. After getting the data we do a insert into this table. and we have a status column in this table.

Which needs to be updated after every steps. We have a one persistence layer class which has all the data base function to call the dao layer methods. We are using annotation for transaction handling.. for this we have added @Transaction on the top of the methods.

In dao.xml we have written something like this -

```
INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_DETAIL(
Column_1, Column_2, Column_3, Column_4
)
&lt;foreach collection="transactionsSubLst" item="element" index="index" separator="union all"&gt;
SELECT

#bean.prop,jdbcType=INTEGER,
#bean.prop2,jdbcType=VARCHAR,
#bean.prop3,jdbcType=VARCHAR,
#bean.prop3,jdbcType=VARCHAR

&lt;/foreach&gt;


&lt;foreach collection="transactionsSubList" item="element" index="index" separator=";"&gt; 
UPDATE TRANSACTION_DETAIL
&lt;set&gt;

Column_3=#element.targetSystem,
Column_4=#element.ruleName,
Column_2=#element.ruleVersion,
Column_1=#element.weightage

&lt;/set&gt;
&lt;where&gt;
Column_1=#element.transactionNo
AND Column_2=#element.requestNumber 

&lt;/where&gt;
&lt;/foreach&gt;
```

When we ran this on single node... then we are fine, but as we move to multiple node, we start getting DeadLock on updates..

Comment: which transaction isolation level ? it also depends on how th SGBD works / is configured.

Comment: we are using cp03 for connection pooling, in cp03 we have a property <property name="connectionCustomizerClassName value="x.y.v.abcClass" />  here we have below code -                                      @Override
 public void onAcquire(Connection c, String parentDataSourceIdentityToken) throws Exception {
  super.onAcquire(c, parentDataSourceIdentityToken);
  c.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
 } . I did't get the TERM SGBD...please explain.